# How to animate image inside SVG (with CSS?)

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I've got an svg with an image inside, and I'm wondering can I animate this with CSS?

I've got it to transform when hovered over, but it's jumping a little which is a weird effect, but then I thought I guess there might be the possibility to make it look more natural if it's animated, such as with a bounce effect which I've seen done in the CSS3 animations.

Anyone got any ideas on how I could do this from inside an svg (a png inside a text character)?

It looks nicer on my site than it does in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Wy6/), in which it goes a bit blurry for some reason.

SVG code:

```
<svg width="50px" height="50px" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" style="width: 50px;height: 50px;">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="118" height="108"><image xlink:href="https://31.media.tumblr.com/9766ee4952b593bbc1af5e2d2249c858/tumblr_inline_mxnnn7dXwh1s16nrs.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
<text x="0" y="0" font-size="59" fill="url(#img1)">
        <tspan x="-1" y="49">▼</tspan>
    </text>

</svg>
```

**No** JS or frameworks plz

**UPDATE** So I found the  tag for SVG but I wouldn't be able to rotate the image or have it move around (would I?) without moving the whole object (i.e. the triangle, which isn't what I'm after...)

The fiddle is now animating opacity (albeit not very well, never reaches fully opaque)

**UPDATE 2** Randak says in the comments it looks blurry on my site, I'm on the latest stable Chrome (Chrome OS) and it looks good at small and large...
[image][image]

Comment: Not exactly seeing the jumping. What exactly do you want it to do? It is unclear what kind of animation you want.

Comment: If you remove the <animate> property from the fiddle you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Any smooth-looking animation would be cool. Perhaps if the image were to move around with a bounce effect or something, that is if the image can be animated separately

Comment: One of the biggest issues with this is your image is getting very blurry when you expand it. StackOverflow isn't a place for opinions on what kind of animation to use – if you want help making a specific animation, you can ask about that, but it is your job to decide what you want.

Comment: I wrote in the question that I'm looking for a bounce effect, with either a rotate or move the image displayed within the triangular portion and elaborated when you asked that it's got to animate the image - gimme a break! The blur issue isn't occurring on [my actual site](http://biochemistri.es/#hovertag), again if you read the question...

Comment: Actually, it is blurry on that site. I'll get back to you with a bounce effect. Bounce like a program loading on a Mac bounce?

Comment: Um I've never used a Mac.. Except this one time in an Apple store but I'm poor haha.. like a [bouncing ball](http://bl.ocks.org/imkevinxu/4402301) Will post screenshots cuz I don't see it blurry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43089/discussion-between-randak-and-lmmx)

Comment: @randak How did your discussion go? Any information you can share?

Comment: Not really anything of note; @lmmx had to go. Basically just interested if it can work for an SVG. I can't seem to get rid of the glitching when it shrinks.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the "jumping" you see is snapping to different fontsizes when scaling. You could use `text-rendering: geometricPrecision` to hopefully eliminate that. However, if your shape is just a triangle, why not just use a `<path>` element instead? That is usually better and will always transition smoothly.

Here's an example of using a path element with a pattern: http://jsfiddle.net/N7njg/ (unfortunately it seems chrome has a bug with animating the x attribute of a pattern).

Comment: That was my first plan, forgot about that. Couldn't create a path in [SVG-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html) though so tried to experiment with other ways. The jumping was to do with the scale of the image inside the text character (which actually transitioned v nicely)

Comment: Actually figured out how to get paths and svg code - looks so much nicer!

Comment: You can also do some basic animation of the image in a group or something in SVG, so like http://jsfiddle.net/n7Wy6/8/ which will rotate etc (you can even time it with mouseover, but that can get a bit fiddly).

Comment: Timing with a mouseover, would need refining, and not sure you mean movement like this anyway, but posting in case it helps give some ideas http://jsfiddle.net/n7Wy6/10/ even though its not a css solution.

Comment: Ideally if I could combine something like the animation in that with a clipPath on a larger version of that image, allowing it to move around without going off into whitespace... The mouseover idea is neat http://jsfiddle.net/n7Wy6/11/ Just trying to figure out how I can clip the polygon... The path format looks wrong in my code compared to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) - i.e. I have [relative coordinates](http://www.svgbasics.com/paths.html)

Comment: You can either use a pattern (which will tile automatically if you want), or you can use a clipPath (which will not tile automatically). I would suggest the former, just set the fill of the path to be the pattern.